# Can't build iOS module during to library conflict

Tags: java, ios, android-studio

I've got a major problem:

I recently started porting my android app to iOS using intels multi os engine. Basically I can work as I expected and there are no major problems developing the app...

...until now: When I want to implement a java module (I am using for my android app as well) to my iOS module, I can't build the iOS module anymore. The module I am implementing uses a json.jar lib and contains some little code necessary for my app. The problem has to do something about the json.jar library implementation as I am getting the following error:

```
Pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method iterator()Ljava/util/Iterator; in class Lorg/json/JSONArray; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.json.JSONArray' appears in /Users/*censored*/.moe/moe-sdk-1.3.6/sdk/moe-core.dex)
```

I really don't know what's the problem as this setup works well with my android module. I hope someone has experienced that problem as well and found a solution willing to share it here!

Thanks in advance.

Additional screenshots:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnvmW.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEQGi.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS02o.png

Note: The last image shows the module which I am accessing via code and is causing the error message above. (It uses it's json module dependency)

If you have any other questions or information requirements, please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a problem of the multi os engine's (1.3) class loading system. There is already the default android json library which is causing a conflict for the class loader as they are both located in the same package.

Either you **change the package** of you json library or you **update** to multi os engine 2.0.0-alpha-1 as they have fixed this issue for the upcoming update.